after calling github actions api to trigger a workflow, how to know the workflow id?
I have this curl command to trigger a workflow in github actions
# Trigger the workflow
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token ${MY_GITHUB_PAT}" https://enterprise-github-url/api/v3/repos/ssce/ssce-selenium-automation/actions/workflows/main.yaml/dispatches -d '{
  "ref":"workflow-name",
  "inputs": {
    "input1": "foo",
    "input2": "bar"
  }
}'

it does not return any the workflow id of the workflow created
What I can do is that I can run this
response=$(curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token ${MY_GITHUB_PAT}" "https://enterprise-github-url/api/v3/repos/ssce/ssce-selenium-automation/actions/workflows/main.yaml/runs?branch=main&per_page=1")

# Extract the run ID
run_id=$(echo $response | jq -r '.workflow_runs[0].id')

echo $run_id

but because of the race conditions, it does not make sense to do this. I might get the id of the wrong workflow.
What should I do? how to get the id of the workflow triggered?
